# How to turn off screen with smart lock Lollipop Pogramatically

Tags: android, locking

Is there any way to lock the phone or turn the screen off and make it work with smart lock the next time I turn it on?

If I turn it off programatically the next time that I turn on the screen it dosen't start any smart lock process and looks like I didn't have the smart lock on.

Thanks

Comment: Do you find any solution? I also want to unlock the screen using smartlock

Comment: @user8430 the current answer does not work for you?

Comment: Current solution using devicepolicymanager. It cannkt unlock if the phone locked using pattern. Hence, i want to use smartlock. Do you use smartlock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that currently. Using `DevicePolicyManager.lockNow()` to turn off the screen and lock the device crashes the `GoogleTrustAgent`. There is an open issue for this bug at the Android Open Source Project see [Issue 79735](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79735). Hope it will be fixed soon.